# TFS file modification and Server workspace

Tags: tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

We are trying to modify some files on the server and then check them back in, before continuing the build.

We do `msbuild /t:updateuid`   to update the XAML files and then I'm thinking using a tf checkin command for checking the files back in.

**Problem A:** TFS won't recognize file changes. We are using a "Server" workspace - is this preventing TFS from finding the changed files?
If I issue a "tf status" from command prompt, TFS won't find the changed files.

**Problem B:** Since the tf command will check files in. It might just trigger another build. Probably a minor issue, since the loop hopefully ends there...

Answer (score 1):

**Problem A:**

As it is a server workspace, you need to perform a `tf checkout` on the files before changing them. They will then show up in the workspace as a pending change.

**Problem B:**

End your check in comment with `***NO_CI***` - this will stop any CI builds from triggering.

e.g. `Modified by Build ***NO_CI***`

If this is a gated build you may need to do other things.